# What is the word used to say the roads are very convenient for you to go because you don't have to changes lanes or many lanes?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

If you don't have to change lanes or just have to change few lanes when going from A to B, it is very easy for you because changing lanes are dangerous and not convenient.

When I look for a school for my children, I often take that into account.

Do we have a phrase to say the roads are very convenient for you to go because you don't have to changes lanes or many lanes?

For example, I have look for a right-roaded school for my children. (Like the way we say "right-handed").

Comment: There is no simple way to say this.  Your wording seems to work well.  *I chose this route because I don't have to change lanes as often as I do on other routes.*

Comment: @EllieK, Do we have something like "**right-roaded**" or alike?

Comment: Tom - no we don't.

Comment: You could describe the route as "simple", which gives a general idea of why you like it without being as detailed as you'd wish.

Comment: You could also say 'straightfoward'.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a context where the need to ***change lanes*** would be an important consideration regarding a journey. If there's a single road that goes all the way from your starting location to your destination, you don't necessarily need to change lanes at all (unless you need to overtake a slow-moving lorry, for example). What might put you off is a lot of ***junctions / turnings*** - where you need to leave one road and merge into traffic on a *different* road.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - aren't all those things part of being a driver? Changing lanes isn't usually 'dangerous' if you do it properly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Over 50 years ago I commuted 20 miles up the A3 with my father for my summer vacation job. We shared the driving - but he being less used to heavy traffic than me, he avoided lane-switching himself, and tutted at me for doing it. But careful noting of journey times, and which vehicles we passed (and which passed *us*) over several weeks eventually led me to concede the truth of what he always claimed. My constant lane-switching rarely shaved even one minute off our hour-long drive to work. But it *was* his car, and there's always a *chance* of a shunt, so I changed my ways! :)

Comment: Do you avoid left turns, or at least left turns that don't have a dedicated left-turn signal? That was my first thought when you mentioned right-roaded/right-handed. I've been known to go around a block to avoid a left turn on a busy road.

Comment: This question is just silly. I have looked at the last 10 questions from this OP and he never accepts any answers. Yet, we sure do work hard for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would most likely say:

- It's a *direct* route.

A direct route is the one that involves the least amount of turns and keeps you broadly travelling in the right direction for the majority of your journey. This is in contrast to:

- The shortest route (the shortest distance overall)
- The fastest route (the one that takes the least amount of time)
- The most economical route (the one that is calculated to use the least fuel or cost the least)

These latter kinds of routes can often involve *more* turns and road changes to take 'shortcuts', or sometimes involve travelling away from your destination for a time just to keep on roads where you can maintain a certain speed.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to say something like:

- I look for the simplest route.

or I like this better:

- I look for the easiest route that avoids (whatever it is you want to avoid).